# Are Query Expressions possible with OpenApi (Swagger)?

Tags: sql, f#, odata, openapi, query-expressions

I was asked to improve/modernize an older webtool, and part of this was the request to add an OpenApi specification to the project. This was done with the specific intend in mind to run query expression on it similar to the ones shown in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions) for OData. Now i am quite the beginner in web programming, even for programming itself and i don't know if something like this can be done for OpenApi or how to approach this problem. I am using FSharp with the SAFE stack, and i am currently writing the OpenApi specification by hand.